# Django ORM - filter doesn't apply to a set

Tags: django

Why filter doesn't apply? It returns the all details records for each master.

## models

```
class Master(models.Model):
    pass

class Detail(models.Model):
    master      = models.ForeignKey(Master, models.CASCADE, related_name='details')
    some_field  = models.BooleanField()
```

## serializers

```
class DetailListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Detail
        fields = ('some_field',)
    
class MasterListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    details = DetailListSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Master
        fields = ('id', 'details')
```

## views

```
data = Master.objects.filter(details__some_field=True)
serializer = MasterListSerializer(data, many=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```py
data = Master.objects.filter(details__some_field=True)
```

you're retrieving a queryset with one `Master` object for each `Detail` object in the database that has `some_field=True`. Those individual `Master` objects that make up the queryset still have *all* of their child `details` per standard Django ORM relations, as you can see if you were to do the following:

```py
for master in data:
    print(master.details.all())
```

You merely retrieved `Master`s you know have at least one `Detail` child with `some_field=True`. (And as such, the `data` queryset could have duplicate `Master` objects, since a `Master` may have multiple `Detail` children with `some_field=True`.)

---

For workarounds, one alternative is to add custom logic in your `MasterListSerializer` that limits which `details` are shown for a given `Master`. Something like:

```py
# Serializers
class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Detail
        fields = ('some_field',)

class MasterWithFilteredDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    details = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_details(self, master):
        # Filter to only include the relevant Details with some_field=True
        qs = master.details.filter(some_field=True)
        serializer = DetailSerializer(instance=qs, many=True)
        return serializer.data

    class Meta:
        model = Master
        fields = ('id', 'details')

# Views
# Note that we use `distinct` here to avoid duplicates
masters = Master.objects.filter(details__some_field=True).distinct()
serializer = MasterWithFilteredDetailsSerializer(masters, many=True)
```

Or perhaps if it works for you, you could do the query and serialization the other way around, starting with `Detail`s with `some_field=True`, like:

```py
# Serializers
class MasterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Master
        fields = ('id',)

class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    master = MasterSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Detail
        fields = ('some_field', `master`,)

# Views
details = Detail.objects.filter(some_field=True).select_related('master')
details_with_masters = DetailSerializer(details, many=True)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for a very detailed answer!

Comment: Happy to help. If you feel this answers the question, it's best to "Accept" the answer so the question shows as resolved. Thanks!